# Increasing the connecting link length in d3 when the node is expanded

Tags: d3.js

I am working on collapsible force layout in d3.The problem I am facing is I need to increase the length of the link between the nodes when it is clicked keeping the link distance same among the childs.

How to increase the distance between analytics and flare when analytics is expanded keeping distance to its children small?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pria_3/70qy8ps6/6/   Refer this code

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288     As it is happening here

Comment: With regret, I have downvoted for circumventing the restriction to require code in questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this by defining a function for the *force.linkDistance*
something like this:

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .linkDistance(function(d){
        if(d.target._children){
            return 50;//target is not expanded so link distance is 50
        } else {
            return 200;//target is expanded so link distance is 200
        }
    })
```

Full working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/77a5svf6/1/).

Comment: In the same code can i have the leaf nodes unclickable if json contains a blank child array in it??

Comment: Hi Cyril..i just noticed a little strange behaviour in the demo...sometimes the size is getting increased and sometimes it tends to be the same.Its happening mostly when collapsing and expanding again..Any idea??

Comment: That is because of this line _.attr("r", function(d) {
       return d._children ? d.size ? 14 : 18 : d.children ? 24 : 10 ; });_ we are changing the radius on collapse if you want it constant then do _.attr("r", function(d) {
       return 10; });

Comment: But I strictly need these 2 behaviours go side by side and one more confusion why would radius of node will affect the link  size on collapsing

Comment: And it is happening even if i make radius constant.You can collapse flare and see.Link size will not increase

Comment: No in the demo http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/77a5svf6/1/ i am talking about line no 133. This is the section responsible for increasing the size of radius

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pria_3/6r0w68L5/2/     check this demo even if you make size constant the size of link dont increase.You can collapse flare and see. I have used your demo only

Comment: Hi Cyril. This looks like a very helpful answer, but please refrain from asking for upvotes and accepts - it isn't really in the spirit of the site, I doubt it makes much difference in practice, and thus it just forms noise to be edited out. It's OK to remind people in comments, if you feel they are a new user who doesn't know how the system works.

Comment: I've edited these out, and have now noticed you frequently [add a deliberate typo for "the"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3382204+teh). I've never understood the point of this meme, but again it is appreciated if you can just spell words properly. Stack Overflow isn't a forum like most other sites, and thus there is - rightly or wrongly - a greater expectation that it is treated like a professional resource. Hope that helps. If you have any comments, feel free to invite me to a chat, or post a general query on _Meta_.