# Overlay a function over a bar chart in D3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Suppose I create a bar chart from some data that I have. This bar chart is generated on a set of x- and y- axes. How can I plot a function (in the form `y=f(x)`) as a line over that same set of axes? I want to do this so that you can easily compare the trends shown by the bar chart and the function.

Comment: Can someone please tell me why this is deserving of downvoting/being closed? I have a problem that I cannot solve, as I haven't found a single piece of D3 documentation that answers this. I thought that there's a good chance that someone from here, a website for programmers, might have encountered this before, and come up with or found a solution.

Comment: I'm guessing people downvoted/voted to close because you don't have a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You could post the code for your barchart, with some data, and an example function you would want to plot.

Comment: The code is irrelevant: I want to know how to do this for a generic bar chart. The function is irrelevant for the same reason: it could be x, sin x, cos x, exp(x), it could be djdjcdhbf(x) for that matter.

Comment: Yes but it's easier to play around if there is some code, sample data etc...

Comment: I think this is a very open ended question. There is no explanation on how a bar chart is related to the f(x) for which you want to make a line chart. what should be the domain(x axis /yaxis) of the graph .

Comment: @Cyril The implication was that the domain would be the same as the domain of the bar chart, and the range would be enough to display the full function across said domain. The relation of the function to the bar chart is surely irrelevant.

Comment: @Bluefire so some bar chart with some domain on the same domain show any function graph.

Comment: It sounds easy enough if you just make a line naively joining the same values as the bars, but if you want to show the "in-between" values it would get difficult quickly if asymptotes and/or inflections are involved e.g. y = 1/x;

Comment: I find your question well-formulated and of relevance. But that's because I actually read and try to understand the issue you're tackling in a generic way to be able to extrapolate the results in general cases. Not every user of SO has that predisposition. (I'm not saying that people are dumb. But I'm really not claiming the opposite, neither, hehe.)

Comment: Bluefire, do you have a simple example to add to this? I appreciate you believe that one is not necessary, but it seems it would be harmless to add it, and would insulate the question from being put on hold in the future. It does feel rather brief to me in the general case, for a _Stack Overflow_ question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am making use of D3 and [Math.js](http://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html).

The reason I am using Math.js is that the function can be very complex
from:

- 4 * sin(x) + 5 * tan(x/2)
- 4 * sin(x^2) + 5 * cos(x/2)^3
- Anything but f(x) :)

You can define your any domain of your  choice here:

```
//define xDomain change it domain of your choice    
var xDomain = [-10, 10];
//define yDomain change it domain of your choice    
var yDomain = [-10, 10];
```

Then make the conventional bar chart for the domain nothing special this is  a standard D3 code for making bar charts.

```
//make the bar chart by loading the tsv
d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  //make x axis
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + y(0) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
  //make y axis
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ",0)")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Frequency");
  //make bar chart rectangle
  svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.letter) - 10;
    })
    .attr("width", 20)
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.frequency);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height / 2 - y(d.frequency);
    });
  makeLineFunction();

});
```

This is my function which will make the line chart based on the value entered in the text box(for the xdomain):

```
function makeLineFunction() {
  //remove any line if present
  d3.selectAll(".line").remove();
  //make an array of all x points
  var xArray = d3.range(xDomain[0], xDomain[1], 0.5);
  //get the formula from the text box above
  var value = d3.select("#function_text").node().value;
  //generate the data using math.js
  var data = xArray.map(function(x1) {
    return {
      x: x1,
      //using math.js for evaluating y point for the given x
      y: math.eval(value, {
        x: x1
      })
    };
  });
  //make the path
  svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);
}
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/TnEQAFBMZOikkL0AJxw6?p=preview), necessary comments added for help.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Text input to accept/draw an arbitrary function is a nice touch!

Comment: @halfer if you want to edit something fine and fix grammars do it... but why did you downvote it for no reason..the answer may be of no use to you but its helpful to others and moreover its completely clear on what i am trying to explain. This is very low on your side.

Comment: Hi Cyril. I downvoted because I made a request to you [on 14th Feb](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32883524/472495) not to add deliberate mistakes to questions (of which I found 90 or so examples across your otherwise helpful answers). Not only did you not reply, as would have been polite, but in the post above you've carried on doing it.

Comment: As I noted on that earlier comment, there is an expectation that Stack Overflow is treated like a professional resource (see [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293779/472495) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165504)). Readers generally do not like all-caps writing, lazy all-lower-case mobile phone posting, etc. We try to be reasonably tolerant of poor spelling and English (and often will fix it silently) but meme errors are different, since the writer is _deliberately_ creating editing work (i.e. an extra burden on volunteers).

Comment: I did indeed downvote, but if you regularly read _Meta_ you'll find that many of us regard it not as a spiteful device but as a message to encourage good behaviour (or discourage negative behaviours). Thus there is no "low" malice at all - I am just taking steps as best as the available tools allow to try to improve the quality of material on the site. It's worth noting that to a person whose first language is not English, _teh_ may be rather confusing!

Comment: If you are willing to commit to not making this error in the future, I will reverse my downvote and you will have my grateful thanks. As I noted on the other thread, you are also most welcome to ask a question on _Meta_ if you feel I have treated you unfairly.

Answer (score 3):

You just generate the data to feed to d3 by running the function over the desired values of the domain and then use for example line genrators to draw the line.

```js
var w = 400;
var h = 400;
var padding = 50;

var svg = d3.select('svg').attr('width', w + padding * 2).attr('height', h + padding * 2);

var xScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([-10, 10]).range([0, w]);
var yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([2, -2]).range([0, h]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale);
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");

var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + "," + padding + ")");

g.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0, " + w / 2 + ")").call(xAxis);
g.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + h / 2 + ", 0)").call(yAxis);

var line = d3.svg.line().interpolate("basis")
  .x(function(d, i) {
    return xScale(d.x);
  })
  .y(function(d, i) {
    return yScale(d.y);
  })
g.append('path')
  .data([fn1()])
  .attr("d", line);

g.append('path')
  .data([fn2()])
  .attr("d", line);

g.append('path')
  .data([fn3()])
  .attr("d", line);

g.append('path')
  .data([fn4()])
  .attr("d", line);

function fn1() {
  function f(x) {
    return Math.cos(x);
  }
  return _.chain(_.range(-10, 10)).map(function(x) {
    return {
      y: f(x),
      x: x
    };
  }).value();
}

function fn2() {
  function f(x) {
    return Math.sin(x);
  }
  return _.chain(_.range(-10, 10)).map(function(x) {
    return {
      y: f(x),
      x: x
    };
  }).value();
}

function fn3() {
  function f(x) {
    return Math.exp(x);
  }
  return _.chain(_.range(-10, 10)).map(function(x) {
    return {
      y: f(x),
      x: x
    };
  }).value();
}

function fn4() {
  function f(x, m, b) {
    return m * x + b;
  }
  return _.chain(_.range(-10, 10)).map(function(x) {
    return {
      y: f(x, 1, 1),
      x: x
    };
  }).value();
}
```

```css
 path {
   stroke: black;
   fill: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <svg></svg>

</body>
```

Comment: I'm not sure where the *fn1()* comes from. Is it omitted in your example or am I just going blind?

Comment: @KonradViltersten  All functions, fn1() through fn4(), are listed at the bottom of what is currently the 1st block of code in the answer (aka the js/d3 section). I had to scroll down to see it which may be how you missed it.

Comment: @SteveLadavich Ah, scrolling... Yes. I've heard about it once or twice... Right... (I feel so dumb now - of course it was right there, hehe.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which illustrate the line chart over bar chat. You can generate y=f(x) values using jsp or php at run time.
update the data part

```
series: [
    {
        title: 'Column',
        type: 'column',
        axisY: 'y1',
        data: [['A', 1], ['B', 4], ['C', 3],
               ['D', 5], ['E', 2], ['F', 1]]
    },
    {
        title: 'Line',
        type: 'line',
        axisY: 'y2',
        data: [['A', 40], ['B', 60], ['C', 62],
               ['D', 52], ['E', 70], ['F', 75]]
    }
]
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>
    Multiple Axes Example
</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jqchart.com/css/jquery.jqChart.css" /> 
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.21/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://www.jqchart.com/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://www.jqchart.com/js/jquery.mousewheel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://www.jqchart.com/js/jquery.jqChart.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://www.jqchart.com/js/jquery.jqRangeSlider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    <script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var background = {
                type: 'linearGradient',
                x0: 0,
                y0: 0,
                x1: 0,
                y1: 1,
                colorStops: [{ offset: 0, color: '#d2e6c9' },
                             { offset: 1, color: 'white' }]
            };

            $('#jqChart').jqChart({
                title: { text: 'Multiple Axes' },
                border: { strokeStyle: '#6ba851' },
                background: background,
                animation: { duration: 1 },
                shadows: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                axes: [
                    {
                        name: 'y1',
                        location: 'left'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'y2',
                        location: 'right',
                        strokeStyle: '#FCB441',
                        majorGridLines: {
                            strokeStyle: '#FCB441'
                        },
                        majorTickMarks: {
                            strokeStyle: '#FCB441'
                        }
                    }
                ],
                series: [
                    {
                        title: 'Column',
                        type: 'column',
                        axisY: 'y1',
                        data: [['A', 1], ['B', 4], ['C', 3],
                               ['D', 5], ['E', 2], ['F', 1]]
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Line',
                        type: 'line',
                        axisY: 'y2',
                        data: [['A', 40], ['B', 60], ['C', 62],
                               ['D', 52], ['E', 70], ['F', 75]]
                    }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="jqChart" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```