# D3 Collapsible Force Layout Variable Link Length

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been trying to adapt the collapsible force layout shown at the link below.
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130

Can anyone help me understand how I can set the linkdistance to different length for each link instead of having them all be set to one value?

Similar to this question is the example https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288 which appears to allow for individual links to have different lengths. However, I don't understand how the code is accounting for that.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: you can do this with the help linkDistance. please look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882284/increasing-the-connecting-link-length-in-d3-when-the-node-is-expanded

Comment: Thank Cyril this helped a lot. For anyone else that may read this it was realizing that I had to specify that I was referring to the 'target' when defining link distance that was important too.

Answer (score 1):

As Cyril mentioned the code below is useful.

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
.linkDistance(function(d){
    if(d.target._children){
        return 50;//target is not expanded so link distance is 50
    } else {
        return 200;//target is expanded so link distance is 200
    }
})
```

What did it for me was something like:

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
.linkDistance(d.target.nodeproperty)
```

In particular I was not realizing that I had to specify target inside of d.nodeproperty.